# TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects in face detection using haarcascade

Tags: python-3.x

```
import cv2
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
detector=cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

Id=input('enter your id....')
sampleNum=0
while(True):
    ret, img = cam.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = detector.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (255, 0, 0), 2)

        sampleNum=sampleNum+1
        cv2.imwrite("dataSet/User."+Id +'.'+ str(sampleNum) + ".jpg", gray[y:y+h,x:x+w])
        cv2.imshow('frame',img)
    #wait for 100 miliseconds 
    if cv2.waitKey(100) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
    # break if the sample number is morethan 20
    elif sampleNum>20:
        break
cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Edit : 1
when I run the above code it throws an error stating...:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "e:/py_projects/detector.py", line 15, in

```
cv2.imwrite("dataSet/User."+Id +'.'+ str(sampleNum) + ".jpg", gray[y:y+h,x:x+w])
```

TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects

[ WARN:0] terminating async callback

how should I fix this error ?
thanks in advance

Comment: Could you format this code properly? Your indentation is off.

Comment: thanks! hope now it is intended properly .

Comment: Did you try with `str(Id)`?

Comment: @Javier No , but why should I use the  str(Id). I want to have a file name like User1.1, User1.2 .. the number after the point is the samples number

Comment: The only object in the concatenation I see is not a string is `Id`. The conversion I suggest will still show the number you want, but being a string type not an int. Just as you did with `str(sampleNum)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in comments, try converting `Id` to a string object.

```
cv2.imwrite("dataSet/User." + str(Id) + '.' + str(sampleNum) + ".jpg", gray[y:y+h,x:x+w])
```